# De qué forma debo subir proyecto web PHP (MVC) a Heroku?

Tags: php, mvc, web, git, heroku

He subido proyectos en arquitectura "Spagueti" a Heroku y me funcionan perfectamente (por medio de GIT), pero ahora que hice un proyecto con Arquitectura Modelo Vista Controlador (MVC), de qué forma lo puedo hacer? Ya que cuando lo hago me aparece lo siguiente al entrar a la página web.

Nota: Cuando lo pruebo en un servidor local hago lo siguiente: entro en la carpeta public de proyecto y allí en la linea de comando hago: php -S localhost:3000. Esto si funciona perfecto. Lo que no entiendo es como subirlo bien a un servidor en la nube como Heroku.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuacion pantallazo de los archivos de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues imagino que leyendo la [documentación](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php) podrías ver cómo hacerlo. Saludos

Comment: Sigo correctamente todos los pasos, como mencioné, al usar arquitectura Spagueti me funciona correctamente, pero con arquitectura MVC, no funciona y sale error que adjunte a la publicacion al momento deingresar al link generado.

Comment: ¿Usas algún framework? ¿Laravel u otro?

Comment: No, ningún framework.

Comment: ¿Has encontrado la solución? Tengo la misma duda. Saludos

Comment: @ÁngelCruz Aun no amigo

Comment: seguramente falte el configurar las urls https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#using-a-custom-application-level-apache-configuration